# Calculating tangent from a point on a circle?

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, trigonometry, geometry

I'm trying to create an algorithm to find the tangent on a circle so that I can calculate the angle of reflection for that circle when it collides with an object. I know the x and y values of the centre of the circle and the radius. I also have the x and y values for the point of impact with the other object. Any help with how to calculate the tangent perhaps using a Java library would be great, or if anyone has any recommendations on how to calculate the angle of reflection another way would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, are you asking how to find the equation of the tangential line?

Comment: How would you do with a paper & pencil?

Comment: Well, I guess that could be an answer yes, but are there any ways that a Java library could make it easier to do what I am doing? Also whether the whole thing I am doing is a good way to calculate this reflection angle.

Comment: The tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius, so if you have centre and point of contact, it's very easy to determine the tangent.

Comment: @user1055696: there's no magic, just do the basic math (it's nothing more than trigonometry), and then come back with your code if your stuck. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you actually want to calculate the angle of incidence for the circle. For this, you need to know the angle of the circle's movement and the angle of the surface it is bouncing off; the point of collision will not be enough since it is the same no matter the angle the circle collides at. If you have this angle, then the circle's new angle is given by `(360 - circle's angle + (surface's angle * 2)) % 360`. I doubt you keep track of the circle's angle of movement, though you may already have two variables describing its movement, perhaps something along the lines of: "for every update, move circle `dx` units right and `dy` units up". If you have this you can compute the circle's angle in degrees with `(180 / π) * arctan(dy / dx)`. This formula works because `dy / dx` gives the slope of the line created by the movement of the circle across the plane. Once we have the slope, we take the inverse tangent (arctan) of it which gives its angle in radians. Finally we convert that angle to degrees with the `180 / π` part.

This also works if we use the slope of the surface. Say the surface is a line starting at point `(x1, y1)` and ending at point `(x2, y2)`. The surface's slope is found with `(y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)`. Then we can apply the formula as before, substituting the slope of the surface, like so: `(180 / π) * arctan((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))`.

Now you have both the circle and the surface in terms of degrees and can apply the first formula above.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's exactly what I meant. Although, I'm a bit confused as to what the surface's angle is, I mean, what would be used instead of dy and dx to calculate its angle?

Comment: You basically need to find the slope of the surface. Say the surface is a line starting at point `(x1, y1)` and going to point `(x2, y2)`. Then `dy = y2 - y1` and `dx = x2 - x1`.

Comment: Thanks. If the collision is on a corner, will the surface slope be the tangent of the circle at the point of collision? If so how should I get dy and dx out of that slope?

Comment: I don't think so. Like I said in my answer, the point of collision could be the same for different angles and therefore it is impossible to tell how to bounce it back. Instead, try averaging the angles of the two surfaces, then computing a perpendicular angle like so: `((angle1 + angle2) / 2 + 90) % 360`. Use this angle as the surface angle in the first formula I gave in my answer.